# Pass user input as parameter to next view

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to set up a website where users can search for a job by zip code/city/state etc. I am having difficulty passing the search value to a view (I have seen this question asked before, but only when the url is expecting a value from an object i.e `job.id`, but I am trying to get input from a user). Here is my code: 
urls.py:

```
path('search_results/<str:search_input>', job_views.search_results, name = 'search_results'),
```

views.py:

```
def search_results(request, search_input):
    return HttpResponse(search_input) # just trying to see if I have the search_input value
```

template (form is in index.html):

```
 <form action="{% url 'search_results' search_input %}" method="post">
```

Right now I get `Reverse for 'search_results' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['search_results\\/(?P<search_input>[^/]+)$']`. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def search_results(request, search_input): 
    if request.method=='POST':
        return HttpResponse(search_input)
```

Pass search_input as string from template.

```
<form action="{% url 'search_results' 'search_input' %}" method="post">
```